# Add numbers to snake(box plot)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture} [thick, framed]

 \filldraw[fill=green!20] (2.85,0) rectangle (5.7,1);

 \draw (4.45,0)--(4.45,1) node[above]{$\textsc{M}$};

 \draw (5.7,0.5)--(11,0.5);%vandret linie til max

 \draw (2.85,0.5)--(1,0.5);%vandret linie til min

 \draw (11,0.39)--(11,0.61);

 \draw (1,0.39)--(1,0.61);

 \draw (0,-1) -- (11,-1);

    \draw[snake=ticks,segment length=1cm] (0,-1) -- (11,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have numbers( like in a coordinate system) along with the line beneath the boxplot, how to do that?

I am very new with LaTeX so as basic as possible:-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\foreach` loop to place nodes containing the tick labels.

Note that the `snakes` library is deprecated. Instead, you should use the `decorations.pathreplacing` library. The ticks are then added by setting `decoration=ticks, decorate`. You can combine the `\draw` commands for the line and the ticks into a single command by using a `postaction`. Specifying a `postaction` will draw the path a second time, using the options specified in the `postaction` argument. That way, if you want to change the size of your axis, you will only need to change the coordinates once.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture} [thick, framed]
 \filldraw[fill=green!20] (2.85,0) rectangle (5.7,1);
 \draw (4.45,0)--(4.45,1) node[above]{$\textsc{M}$};
 \draw (5.7,0.5)--(11,0.5);%vandret linie til max
 \draw (2.85,0.5)--(1,0.5);%vandret linie til min
 \draw (11,0.39)--(11,0.61);
 \draw (1,0.39)--(1,0.61);
 \draw [
    postaction={
        draw,
        decoration=ticks,
        segment length=1cm,
        decorate,
    }
 ] (0,-1) -- (11,-1);
 \foreach \tick in {0,...,11}
    \node at (\tick,-1) [below=1pt] {\tick};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```