# Change x axis numbers to different values on boxplot,

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to create multiple box plots like the one below, which I obtained from [adding numbers to snake(boxplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67040/add-numbers-to-snakebox-plot).

I want to change the axis to start and finish at different values e.g. Start `12` finish `23`, so I can give them to my students, and they give me the five point summary.

I changed the value to get the last tick. I can create new box plots by changing all the values, but that's very time consuming.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [thick, framed]
        \filldraw[fill=green!20] (2.85,0) rectangle (5.7,1);
    \draw (4.45,0)--(4.45,1); 
    \draw (5.7,0.5)--(11,0.5);%vandret linie til max
    \draw (2.85,0.5)--(1,0.5);%vandret linie til min
    \draw (11,0.39)--(11,0.61);
    \draw (1,0.39)--(1,0.61);
    \draw [
    postaction={ 
        draw,
        decoration=ticks,
        segment length=1cm, % this changes number of ticks
        decorate,
    }
    ] (0,-1) -- (11.005,-1); % 11.005 need for last tick
    \foreach \tick in {0,...,11}
    \node at (\tick,-1) [below=1pt] {\tick};
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With adding new counter in `\foreach` loop you can separate counter for position of tick and value of ticks:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [thick, framed]
    \filldraw[fill=green!20] (2.85,0) rectangle (5.7,1);
\draw (4.45,0)--(4.45,1);
\draw (5.7,0.5)--(11,0.5);%vandret linie til max
\draw (2.85,0.5)--(1,0.5);%vandret linie til min
\draw (11,0.39)--(11,0.61);
\draw (1,0.39)--(1,0.61);
\draw [
postaction={
    draw,
    decoration=ticks,
    segment length=1cm, % this changes number of ticks
    decorate,
}
] (0,-1) -- (11.005,-1); % 11.005 need for last tick
\foreach \tick [count=\x from 0] in {12,...,23} % <----
\node at (\x,-1) [below=1pt] {\tick};           % <----  
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much, Zarko and ZhiyuanLck. I've voted is that the correct way to show appreciation?

Comment: @Jon, so far you not accept any received answers. It will be nice that beside voting you from received answer accept (by clicking on check mark st top left side of answers) one which solve your problem to the best way.

Comment: I have a question, in my settings segment length=1.2cm. How can I align the numbers below?

Comment: @Betelgeuse, accordingly multiply `x` coordinates, or define `x` unit ... I suggest you to ask new question where show what is your problem and what you try so far to solve it. BTW, I'm not sure, if I understand your comment correctly (and comments are not intended for asking new questions)

Answer (score 1):

Another choice with `boxplot` of `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis x line shift=5mm,
  axis y line=none,
  y=1cm,
  xtick distance=1,
  xmin=-0.2, xmax=12.4,
]
\addplot+ [
  fill=green!20, draw=black,
  boxplot prepared={
  lower whisker=1, lower quartile=2.85,
  median=4.45,
  upper quartile=5.7, upper whisker=11,
},
  ] coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis x line shift=5mm,
  axis y line=none,
  y=1cm,
  xtick distance=1,
  xmin=11.8, xmax=24.4,
]
\addplot+ [
  fill=red!20, draw=black,
  boxplot prepared={
  lower whisker=13, lower quartile=14.85,
  median=16.45,
  upper quartile=17.7, upper whisker=23,
},
  ] coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]